# Find an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^{T}AP$ is diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I began by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix}
  4 & 0 & -2 \\
  0 & 2 & -2 \\
  -2 & -2 & 3
 \end{pmatrix}$. This gave $\lambda_1=0, \lambda_2=3$ and $\lambda_3=6$ and $\mathbf{v}_1$ $= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \mathbf{v}_1$ $= \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{v}_3 = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}.$

I then divided each eigenvector by its length and put them all together to make $P=\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 2 & -2 \\
  0 & -2 & -1 \\
  0 & 1 & 2
 \end{pmatrix}$ 
Now $P^{T}AP $ is diagonal as required but the problem is that $P$ isn't orthogonal because $P^{T}P\neq I_3$. I assume this has happened because of there being a $0$ eigenvalue but what should I do about it?

Comment: By definition, $\vec 0$ isn't an  eigenvector.  Try to find a non-zero vector of the kernel of the matrix.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: How did you found $v_2$? Just solve $Ax=\vec0$.

Comment: That's what I tried originally. It gives me the equations: $2x=z$, $y=z$ and $-2x-2y+3z=0$. But isn't the only solution here $x=y=z=0$?

Comment: What about $x=1$, $y=z=2$?

Answer (score 1):

As answered in the comments above: the problem is that we needed an eigenvector for $0$, which by definition could not be the $0$ vector.

On top of this, note that in order to have $P^TP = I$, all columns of $P$ must have length $1$.  Ensure this by normalizing the eigenvectors, that is, dividing all columns of $P$ by their length.